# Classic, but puzzling "The uploaded file could not be moved"

Tags: plugins, errors

Running NGINX, MariaDB and php-fpm. Full error is:

```
    Sorry, there has been an error.
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2016/12.
```

1) Yes, I did "chown -R nginx:nginx" and "chmod -R 755" for the whole html/ directory.

2) Yes, I am using the correct directory.

3) get_current_user() in PHP returns "root" -- I would figure this is contradictive, since the root user should have complete control over the system. This is a completely separate issue imo.

Thanks, this is quite puzzling to me.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out server has SELinux enabled.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/directory_to_write
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/directory_to_write
```

Should alleviate any issues.